# limit $\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\sin x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

how can I solve it?

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\sin x}\right)$

Comment: $\sin x=2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the limit is $\frac{0}{0}$,we can use Lopital Rule
 $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^2 x/2}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2(\sin x/2)(\cos x/2)(0.5)}{\cos x}=0$$

Comment: One should not use Lopital's rule before checking the sufficient conditions for it to be applied

Comment: I meant a more rigorous approach, but nevermind

Answer (score 5):

Use
$$\sin(x)=2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})$$

So
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{x}{2})}=0
$$

Answer (score 3):

Just elementary limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{\sin x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{(x/2)}\right)^{\!2}
\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot x
$$

Comment: That's the best way to do it, although I would have left out the limit signs and called it a hint, or carried it on out to $(1/4)\cdot 1^2\cdot 1 \cdot 0 =0$ at the end.

Comment: @zhw. There were already answers showing the final result. I also like Angelo Mark's solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a bit more straightforward if we make a simple substitution $t=\frac{1}{2}x$.
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\sin x} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 t}{\sin 2t} =\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin(x)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\sin(x)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\cos(x)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sec(x)\right)=$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{0}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{0}{2}\right)\sec(0)=0$$